# Log likelihood to implement Naive Bayes for Text Classification

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, probability, bayesian, text-mining

I am implementing Naive Bayes algorithm for text classification. I have ~1000 documents for training and 400 documents for testing. I think I've implemented training part correctly, but I am confused in testing part. Here is what I've done briefly:

In my training function:

```
vocabularySize= GetUniqueTermsInCollection();//get all unique terms in the entire collection

spamModelArray[vocabularySize]; 
nonspamModelArray[vocabularySize];

for each training_file{
        class = GetClassLabel(); // 0 for spam or 1 = non-spam
        document = GetDocumentID();

        counterTotalTrainingDocs ++;

        if(class == 0){
                counterTotalSpamTrainingDocs++;
        }

        for each term in document{
                freq = GetTermFrequency; // how many times this term appears in this document?
                id = GetTermID; // unique id of the term 

                if(class = 0){ //SPAM
                        spamModelArray[id]+= freq;
                        totalNumberofSpamWords++; // total number of terms marked as spam in the training docs
                }else{ // NON-SPAM
                        nonspamModelArray[id]+= freq;
                        totalNumberofNonSpamWords++; // total number of terms marked as non-spam in the training docs
                }
        }//for


        for i in vocabularySize{
                spamModelArray[i] = spamModelArray[i]/totalNumberofSpamWords;
                nonspamModelArray[i] = nonspamModelArray[i]/totalNumberofNonSpamWords;

        }//for


        priorProb = counterTotalSpamTrainingDocs/counterTotalTrainingDocs;// calculate prior probability of the spam documents
}
```

I think I understood and implemented training part correctly, but I am not sure I could implemented testing part properly. In here, I am trying to go through each test document and I calculate logP(spam|d) and logP(non-spam|d) for each document. Then I compare these two quantities in order to determine the class (spam/non-spam).

In my testing function:

```
vocabularySize= GetUniqueTermsInCollection;//get all unique terms in the entire collection
for each testing_file:
        document = getDocumentID;

        logProbabilityofSpam = 0;
        logProbabilityofNonSpam = 0;

        for each term in document{
                freq = GetTermFrequency; // how many times this term appears in this document?
                id = GetTermID; // unique id of the term 

                // logP(w1w2.. wn) = C(wj)∗logP(wj)
                logProbabilityofSpam+= freq*log(spamModelArray[id]);
                logProbabilityofNonSpam+= freq*log(nonspamModelArray[id]);
        }//for

        // Now I am calculating the probability of being spam for this document
        if (logProbabilityofNonSpam + log(1-priorProb) > logProbabilityofSpam +log(priorProb)) { // argmax[logP(i|ck) + logP(ck)]
                newclass = 1; //not spam
        }else{
                newclass = 0; // spam
        }

}//for
```

My problem is; I want to return the probability of each class instead of exact 1's and 0's (spam/non-spam). I want to see e.g. newclass = 0.8684212 so I can apply threshold later on. But I am confused here. How can I calculate the probability for each document? Can I use logProbabilities to calculate it?

Answer (score 3):

The probability of the data described by a set of features {*F1*, *F2*, ..., *Fn*} belonging in class *C*, according to the naïve Bayes probability model, is

```
P(C|F) = P(C) * (P(F1|C) * P(F2|C) * ... * P(Fn|C)) / P(F1, ..., Fn)
```

You have all the terms (in logarithmic form), except for the 1 / *P*( *F1*, ..., *Fn*) term since that's not used in the naïve Bayes classifier that you're implementing. (Strictly, the [MAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_a_posteriori) classifier.)

You'd have to collect frequencies of the features as well, and from them calculate

```
P(F1, ..., Fn) = P(F1) * ... * P(Fn)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Assume that I've also collected P(F1, ..., Fn) and now I will calculate the P(C|F) like the following: e.g. for a non-spam document: P(C|F) = logProbabilityofNonSpam + log(1-priorProb) - log(P(F1....Fn)). But won't it still be in logarithmic form instead of a probability between 0 and 1? I am a little bit confused.

Comment: Yes, it will be in logarithmic form. You will have to exponentiate it. (Beware of small values, though, as e^x may become zero).